# Тест архива с использованием 7z.dll из кода С

Tags: c, 7z, dll

Всем доброго времени. 
Учусь писать на С, это, по сути, моя первая сколько-нибудь полезная программа.

В общем, замысел такой: из некоторого файла html парсится ссылка на архив *.war. Гуя 7zip-a сообщает, что тип архива zip.

Вопрос 1. Можно ли, используя 7z.dll провести тестирование архива на целостность? 
Вопрос 2. Если можно, то как прикрутить к исходнику на С эту ДЛЛ?

Если нужно, могу выставить код всей программы.

Спасибо!

Comment: Нашел упминание некоей BOOL WINAPI SevenZipCheckArchive(LPCSTR _szFileName, const int _iMode). 
Получается, условие будет "если 0, то cout<< ахтунг"

Comment: посмотрите параметры командной строки. и используйте системный вызов из кода с проверкой возвращаемого значения

Comment: Спасибо, параметры шелла знаю, изначально так и планировалось. Не могу найти информацию о том, что возвращает system(7z t archive.7z).

А не подскажете, можно ли выполнить нечто похожее на var=system(7z t archive.7z)? 

Или значение, возвращаемое системом нельзя запихать в переменную?

upd. Блин, то, что я написал - ахинея, оно либо запихивает в константу целиком функцию, либо ничего не делает :(

Comment: просто проверте в командной строке, сравните два архива один нормальный а второй битый в возвращаемом значении будет либо нуль либо единица наверное

Comment: возвращаются значения ЦРЦ и надпись everything is OK, если архив нормальный, битый пока не пробовал.

C:\Users\Administrator>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Rust_assemb_Dumper.rar

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Rust_assemb_Dumper.rar

Testing     DLLMain.cpp
Testing     Rust_dump.sln
Testing     Rust_dump.vcxproj

Everything is Ok

Files: 3
Size:       7766
Compressed: 2532

Comment: Для system не гарантируется, что она возвращает код завершения процесса, это зависит от реализации. Ее результат свидетельствует о наличии или отсутствии командного процессора, выполнении или невыполнении команды. Посмотрите функцию spawn.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это уже больше похоже на искомое. Буду пробовать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line вот здесь написано как получить результат выполнения.